# Recognize a simple Letter

Tags: c#, ocr, image-recognition, aforge, accord.net

I am trying to determine a an accurate and fast, computational wise, method to recognize a simple capital letter in an image.

I only need to recognize A-Z letters range (only Capitals and no special chars).

Examples:

- Letter "A"

[image: A letter]

- Letter "R"

[image: R letter]

Is there a function or some code that I can utilize to recognize them?

Notes:

- The position of the letter in the cropped image is not ever the same
- I have the original cropped images. So I can apply a compare method to get the most similar image in the set.

Comment: C# OCR Libraries from a quick search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-sharp-ocr-library

Comment: You should like at some OCR libraries.  This one exposes methods through .NET so you can call them from C#, but I haven't used it myself, there's simple example code there in C#:  http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/

Comment: It looks like the whitelist function is great for your needs to: 
`ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");`

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth having a look at the Tesseract source code - it's open and might give you some insights!
However, it'd be much faster to simply use the library than rebuild your own interpretation of it! ;)